# Logging in a C# library

Tags: c#, logging

What is the best practise regarding logging inside a library?

I am creating a C# library to be used by users and at some points I want to log an error or a warning. Is it a good practice to use log4net and log in a file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The beauty of using log4net is that your library doesn't have to specify where something is logged. The destination (log appenders) of the log messages is determined by the configuration, which is specified by the application (typically in a config file).

So yes, use log4net following their recommended patterns (a unique "logger" per class) and inform your users that your library uses log4net. Any log messages that your library code generates will be routed according to the [consumers configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) (file, database, console, trace, etc).

EDIT: Here is [a good short primer](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html) on log4net that explains the basic concepts.

Comment: Indeed, as dpurrington mentioned, log4net lets you leave it up to the consumer of your library *where* they want to log to and the verbosity levels, but you define *what* is logged. You must make sure the root logger in your library is public so it can be accessed by external assemblies though. See here for the problem that I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159189/is-there-a-built-in-logging-framework-in-net

Answer (score 27):

All the answers here seems outdated. I will make a new one:

[My library](https://github.com/duongphuhiep/ToolsPack.NetCore/blob/3548336/src/ToolsPack.Samba/CifsConnectionManager.cs#L16) asks for an optional `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` object to write log messsages. Without the `ILogger` object then it simply won't log anything.

The consumer application can create this `ILogger` object using NLog, Log4Net or SeriLog.. and my library can be used in ASP.NET core application with no log framework lock-in.

Example creating a Microsoft ILogger using other lggging framework

```
private static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder.AddNLog(); //=>install NLog.Extensions.Logging nuget
    //or builder.AddSerilog(); => install Serilog.Extensions.Logging nuget
    //or builder.AddLog4Net() //=> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore
 });
private static readonly ILogger<Program> log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

//configure nlog/serilog/log4net normally then
log.LogInformation("Hello");
```

In case Log4Net, you can also

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddLog4Net(); //load log4net.config by default
```

Comment: Given the logging interface is part of .NET Platform Extensions since 1.0, I think this is the best answer. All the comments about 3rd party library dependencies are now invalid.

Comment: The other answers are indeed outdated and irrelevant with .net core/5 now, and this answer offers a reasonable approach. However keep in mind that doing it this way does have its drawbacks as well: a) versioning headaches (making sure your version of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions lines up with the application's), 2) introduces a required package dependency (nuget does not support the notion of "optional" dependecies), and d) is not supportted if your library wants to support .net <= 4.6

Answer (score 26):

I use log4net in my own library but I would not do this if my library should be used by others (i.e. outside of my organization). In that case I would use an interface for logging, provide a default implementation based on log4net in separate assembly and use one way or another to allow the users of the library to inject their own implementation.

Having said this: I really like log4net and would not use anything else, but I think it is wrong to force others to have to use the logging framework of your choice.

Edit:

- I would also not consider it good practice having the library log to a file by default. The users of your library should be able to decide where log messages end-up.
- I would also provide a "no-operation" implementation that can be used if no logging at all is required. This probably should be default behavior an not require any additional assemblies or steps to implement.

Comment: Have you tried NLog as well?? What's your opinion on that in contrast to log4net?

Comment: No I did not try NLog but the answer would be the same. Let the user of the library decide which logging framework to use.

Comment: Yep, sure. That's fine, but in my case I don't really have to externalize it, but just for internal use. I just wondered whether you have tried nlog as well. thx

Answer (score 7):

I would be wary of introducing a dependency on a 3rd party library such as log4net in a general-purpose class library: I would prefer to leave it to the caller to decide how to do logging.  What if the user of the library is already using a different logging framework?

Some alternatives are:

- For errors, throw an `Exception` or allow one to propagate, and let the caller handle it and do any logging.
- For warnings (e.g. an Exception that you handle in the library), you could consider raising an event that the caller can handle if he wants to log it.  For example, you could raise an `Error` event that takes a `System.IO.ErrorEventArgs` (or a similar custom `EventArgs`) with details of the error.
- If you feel the library needs more instrumentation, you could raise more events at strategic points in your library that the caller can handle to do logging.
- Alternatively, you could define an interface in your class library (`ILogging` or similar) that callers have to implement if they want logging.  Have callers pass an instance of this interface to a class constructor to enable logging.
- You can do something similar to logging in the [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/logging-with-the-aws-sdk-for-net/), i.e. support multiple logging frameworks, but load 3rd party frameworks using reflection so as not to create a dependency.  I personally don't like this, but it's a valid approach, especially if your library is big enough to justify detailed instrumentation.

Comment: Just wanted to touch on your last point re AWS SDK's approach, this is also the approach used by [LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog) (now depracted) and served the community of library developers very well for years. I wish it was still used :( Also, I wish AWS SDK actually did support multiple logging frameworks (i.e. serilog, nlog, etc) however it only supports log4net in terms of 3rd party logging.

Answer (score 3):

log4net is just a 3rd party library, its not *best practice* that you must use that as your logging library when using C#. My advice would be always persist the log to somewhere (most common being a text file). However, there is also the event log (requires a little extra setup).

I tend to use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) which I find is very easy to use and simple to setup. As for logging inside your class libraries its really just which ever approach you feel is best for your application. Some people would create 1 logger and pass it down into the classes, others would create a separate logger per `loggable` class. I tend to create a static logger per class and it works fine.

Comment: nlog does not use log4net in any way.

Comment: Yep it definitely doesn't, not sure why that was in there! Pretty old answer, probably a misunderstanding of how NLog worked back then.

Comment: @james "Some people would create 1 logger and pass it down into the classes..." - how? Class constructor?  "...others would create a separate logger per loggable class. I tend to create a static logger per class and it works fine."  How do you do this? How do you ensure the same log is written to by the calling code and the library?

Comment: @Howiecamp old question but in the interest of completeness something like private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); in each class will give you the 1 logger : 1 class setup. As per ensuring the same log file, your configuration controls the logging rules and targets. Even a single file logger may span multiple files over time and as the size grows.

Comment: @plyawn Thank you for your answer.  If I do `private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(logger_name);` it'll always return the same instance for each unique `logger_name` I specify, right?

Comment: @Howiecamp - actually no, according to the docs here: http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.4.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_GetLogger.htm "Multiple calls to GetLogger with the same argument aren't guaranteed to return the same logger reference."

Comment: @plyawn Wow that's total news to me.  Your link is great - I've got to research this.

Answer (score 3):

Practice vise a good way to do it is to introduce a Logging facade, so you don't care about the logger you use, you have a consistent common interface for the logger.

for e.g you could try [this](http://slf.codeplex.com/) or simply write your own.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it never hurts to wrap logging in your own small adapter, for example, to later easily strip logging from production. I created a [small logging wrapper](https://github.com/cs-util-com/cscore#logging) for this, its API looks like this:

```
Log.d("I'm a log message");
Log.w("I'm a warning with parmas", "param 1", 2, "..");
Log.e("I'm an error");
Log.e(new Exception("I'm an exception"));
AssertV2.IsTrue(1 + 1 == 3, "This assertion will fail");
```

See https://github.com/cs-util-com/cscore#logging for more examples

You can log to the console, a file, Unity and can easily add more complex logging targets like e.g. Serilog

Let me know if you have suggestions or other feedback, I want to keep it as small as possible but want to **learn about use cases** it would not cover yet

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

Do you want to have a logging mechanism for pure technical stuff that you can switch on/off with varying verbosity (for support activities)?
Or do you want to log more business related stuff that is intended to be read by the users of your library?

You should answer these questions first, then you can decide upon what to log, where to store it, and how to format it...

In any case, log4net is a good, mature and stable logging framework for all these purposes. And to log to a rolling file is common practice (but by far not the only option...).

Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

What are your users using for logging?
This is the question which you need to answer to determine the right framework.
Log4net is powerful and relatively easy from my pov. You could also use it to log into a streamwriter if there is nothing else specified.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/).

The nice thing about this program is that you can filter the logs in the viewing app, a feature which is incredibly useful in practice.

For the record, I am not affiliated with SmartInspect in any way.